Data getting corrupted on Upload in Azure Blob
I have some files in Azure Blob and after processing the blobs, I am moving the files to another container.
The file I am getting in the destination folder is junk. What I am doing wrong?
The source file is under the '.log.gz' extension.
[Function("Function1")]
 public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer)
 {
     //Reading the config file. For local it is local.settings.json
     var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
         .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
         .AddEnvironmentVariables()
         .Build();

     string blbobConnectionString = config["AzureWebJobsStorage"];
     BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(blbobConnectionString, "abc");
     BlobContainerClient destinationBlobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(blbobConnectionString, "xyz");


     var blobs = blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync();
     await foreach (var blob in blobs)
     {
         _logger.LogInformation($"Blob Name: {blob.Name}");
         BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);

         using (Stream blobStream = await blobClient.OpenReadAsync())
         using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(blobStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
         using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(decompressionStream, Encoding.Default))
         {
             string line;
             while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
             {
                 // Process the line here
                 Console.WriteLine(line);
             }

             BlobClient destinationBlobClient = destinationBlobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
             blobStream.Position = 0;
             await destinationBlobClient.UploadAsync(blobStream);
         }
         blobClient.DeleteAsync(DeleteSnapshotsOption.None);
     }
 }

Edit 1:
I re-read the blob for uploading but still get the same error. Following is the updated code.
  [Function("Function1")]
  public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer)
  {
      _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
      
      if (myTimer.ScheduleStatus is not null)
      {
          _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
      }

      //Reading the config file. For local it is local.settings.json
      var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
          .AddEnvironmentVariables()
          .Build();

      string blbobConnectionString = config["AzureWebJobsStorage"];

      BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(blbobConnectionString, "abc");

      BlobContainerClient destinationBlobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(blbobConnectionString, "xyz");


      var blobs = blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync();
      await foreach (var blob in blobs)
      {
          _logger.LogInformation($"Blob Name: {blob.Name}");
          BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);

          using (Stream blobStream = await blobClient.OpenReadAsync())
          using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(blobStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
          using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(decompressionStream, Encoding.Default))
          {
              string line;
              while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
              {
                  // Process the line here
                  Console.WriteLine(line);
                  JObject json = JObject.Parse(line);
                  string dateOfEvent = System.Convert.ToString( json["Datetime"]);
                  string datePattern = "M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt";
                  DateTime parsedDate;

                  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateOfEvent, datePattern, null,  DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
                      Console.WriteLine("Parsed date: "+ parsedDate);

                  json["Datetime"] = parsedDate;

                  line = json.ToString();

                  Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ"));
                 dateOfEvent = parsedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                  var datestring = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("r");
                  var jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
                  string stringToHash = "POST\n" + jsonBytes.Length + "\napplication/json\n" + "x-ms-date:" + datestring + "\n/api/logs";
                  string hashedString = BuildSignature(stringToHash, sharedKey);
                  string signature = "SharedKey " + customerId + ":" + hashedString;
          
                  PostData(signature, datestring, line);
              }
          }


          BlobClient destinationBlobClient = destinationBlobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
          //blobStream.Position = 0;
          await destinationBlobClient.UploadAsync(await blobClient.OpenReadAsync());

          blobClient.DeleteAsync(DeleteSnapshotsOption.None);
      }
  }


What if you open the source stream again OpenReadAsync in a new using block and do the upload there?

@Magnus: I re-read the blog in another attempt but still getting the same issue. I have updated the question with new code under Edit 1.

Why are you downloading and uploading the blob if you want to copy blob from one container to another? You can simply use copy blobs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob?tabs=microsoft-entra-id).

Is the new blob of the same size as the original?

Thanks @GauravMantri, I missed those methods. I was able to do it with StartCopyFromUri


Data getting corrupted on Upload in Azure Blob

I agree with Gaurav Mantri's comment, To copy a blob from one container to another container you can use the StartCopyFromUriAsync() method with Azure .Net SDK.
Code:
string blobConnectionString = config["AzureWebJobsStorage"];

BlobContainerClient sourceBlobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(blobConnectionString, "abc");
BlobContainerClient destinationBlobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(blobConnectionString, "xyz");

var blobs = sourceBlobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync();

await foreach (var blob in blobs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Copying Blob: {blob.Name}");

    BlobClient sourceBlobClient = sourceBlobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
    BlobClient destinationBlobClient = destinationBlobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
    Uri sourceBlobUri = sourceBlobClient.Uri;

    CopyFromUriOperation copyOperation = await destinationBlobClient.StartCopyFromUriAsync(sourceBlobUri);
    await copyOperation.WaitForCompletionAsync();

    BlobProperties properties = await destinationBlobClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"Blob: {blob.Name} - Copy Status: {properties.CopyStatus}");

    await sourceBlobClient.DeleteAsync();
}

Console.WriteLine("Blob Copy Process Completed.");


The above code will copy blobs from one container to another container and
delete the source blobs.
Output:
Blob Copy Process Started...
Copying Blob: sample_log.gz
Blob: sample_log.gz - Copy Status: Success
Blob Copy Process Completed.

Reference:
Copy a blob with asynchronous scheduling using .NET - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn
